# GWT Filter never executed

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, web-crawler, servlet-filters

I am developing a GWT Filter to make my GWT app crawlable. The idea is that when it finds a ugly URL like this:

http://www.myapp.com/?_escaped_fragment_=v;id=Mv67mC13Yizr

Presents the good one:

http://www.myapp.com/#!v;id=Mv67mC13Yizr

However, the code never reachs the doFilter(). Why?

**Web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**DispatchServletModule.java**

```
public class DispatchServletModule extends ServletModule {

    @Override
    public void configureServlets() {
        serve("/" + ActionImpl.DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME)
                .with(DispatchServiceImpl.class);
        filter("/").through(CrawlerServiceImpl.class);
    }
}
```

**CrawlerServiceImpl.java**

```
    @Singleton
    public final class CrawlerServiceImpl implements Filter {
      private static final String ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT1 = "_escaped_fragment_=";
      private  final int ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_LENGTH1 = ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT1.length();
      private static final String ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT2 = "&"+ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT1;
      private  final int ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_LENGTH2 = ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT2.length();

      @Inject(optional = true)
      private final Provider<WebClient> webClientProvider = null;

      @Override
      public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {  
      }
      @Override
      public void destroy() {
      }

      @Override
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
          FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String queryString = req.getQueryString();

        final String requestURI = req.getRequestURI();
        if ((queryString != null) && (queryString.contains(ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT1))) {
          try {
            StringBuilder pageNameSb = new StringBuilder("http://");
            pageNameSb.append(req.getServerName());
            if (req.getServerPort() != 0) {
              pageNameSb.append(":");
              pageNameSb.append(req.getServerPort());
            }
            pageNameSb.append(requestURI);
            queryString = rewriteQueryString(queryString);
            pageNameSb.append(queryString);
            String pageName = pageNameSb.toString();
            WebClient webClient;
            if( webClientProvider == null )
              webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
            else
              webClient = webClientProvider.get();

            webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage( pageName );

            res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
            out.println("<hr />");
            out.println("<center><h3>You are viewing a non-interactive page that is intended for the crawler.  "
                + "You probably want to see this page: <a href=\""
                + pageName
                + "\">"
                + pageName + "</a></h3></center>");
            out.println("<hr />");     
            out.println(page.asXml());
            webClient.closeAllWindows();
            out.println("");
            out.close();
          }
          catch( Exception e ) {
          }
        } else {
          chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
      }

      private String rewriteQueryString(String queryString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        int index = queryString.indexOf(ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT2);
        int length = ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_LENGTH2;
        if (index == -1) {
          index = queryString.indexOf(ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_FORMAT1);
          length = ESCAPED_FRAGMENT_LENGTH1;
        }
        if (index != -1) {
          StringBuilder queryStringSb = new StringBuilder();
          if (index > 0) {
            queryStringSb.append("?");
            queryStringSb.append(queryString.substring(0, index));
          }
          queryStringSb.append("#!");
          queryStringSb.append(URLDecoder.decode(queryString.substring(index
              + length, queryString.length()), "UTF-8"));
          return queryStringSb.toString();
        }
        return queryString;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<url-pattern>` is invalid, `*` is only allowed as a `/*` suffix or a `*.` prefix of the pattern; and patterns apply only to the path, not the query-string.

You have to map your filter to `/` and within the filter check for the `_escaped_fragment_` parameter (I'd personnaly check that `getMethod()` is `"GET"` and then use `getParameter("_escaped_fragment_")`) to decide whether to use your `WebClient` to fetch and render the page on the server-side, or simply chain to the next filter.

Note that as you declare your filter in your `web.xml` it won't be injected by Guice, so like [Dvd Prd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15945388/116472) said you'd probably rather declare the filter in your Guice's `ServletModule`. Note that similarly to *standard* mappings, only the path is matched, so the above still applies (and even a `filterRegex()` wouldn't work).

Comment: Thanks. Then, following what you say on your last paragraph, from the code above I have just removed this filter entries from web.xml, and inserted the code Dvd Prd suggests on my DispatchServletModule.java. But still doesn't work. Please find above the new code.

Comment: As I said, the pattern is only matched on the path, so even binding in the Guice `ServletModule` you have to bind to `/` and modify your filter to handle the query-string (first part of my response)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated it again:  filter("/").through(CrawlerServiceImpl.class); However, the code inside doFilter() is never executed. Any ideas?

Comment: If your `/` is a static page *and* you serve your app from AppEngine, then [this is expected](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Servlets_and_URL_Paths); otherwise I don't know. Have you set a breakpoint within `GuiceFilter` to see if it's invoked at all and with which URL?

Answer (score 0):

Guice takes all filters. To add a filter you need to declare it in your guice [servlet module](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule):

`filter("/?_escaped_fragment_=*").through(CrawlerServiceImpl.class);`

Comment: The `GuiceFilter` is declared and mapped after the `CrawlerServletFilter` so that one will be executed before the `GuiceFilter`.